# Qual a diferença entre AppCompatActivity e Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

- Qual a diferença da `AppCompatActivity` para `Activity` ?
- A partir de qual versão a `AppCompatActivity` foi adicionada ao `Android`?

Answer (score 10):

A diferença reside em que a [AppCompactActivity](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) permite, recorrendo à [support library](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/tools/support-library/index.html), usar o [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html)(introduzido na *API level 11*) em aplicações a partir da *API level 7*.

Após a revisão 22.1 a [support library](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/tools/support-library/index.html) inclui também suporte ao *material color palette*, *widget tinting* e *Toolbar*.

A partir da revisão 24.2 a classe [ActionBarActivity](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html), que até aí servia para esse propósito, foi considerada obsoleta.

Assim, para que as aplicações que usam as facilidades atrás referidas possam correr na *API level 7* ou superior, terá de fazer as suas *Activities* herdar de [AppCompactActivity](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html).

Em relação em qual versão a classe foi adicionada julgo que ela existe desde que a [support library(v4)](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/tools/support-library/index.html) foi introduzida em Março de 2011. No entanto foi com a sua actualização na revisão 22.1(Abril de 2015) que ela passou a ser a classe base para as *Activities* utilizarem [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html) em *"modo de compatibilidade"*.